# can insert new row in null cachedrowset?

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset, cachedrowset

There is `SQLException java.lang.NullPointerException` when `moveToInsertRow()` method called.

```
rsStock.moveToInsertRow();

rsStock.updateInt(1, 1);

rsStock.updateInt(2, 1);

rsStock.insertRow();

rsStock.moveToCurrentRow();
```

Comment: `rsStock` is `null`, 100%. We cannot tell you why, debug your code and post relevant parts please.

Comment: check why rsStock could be null. java.lang.NullPointerException is not an SQLException.

Comment: Post the stack trace. Unclear what you mean by 'null CachedRowSet'. Do you mean *empty* CachedRowSet?